# Couldn't upload file using multer in node js + angular js application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, multer

I want to upload a file in a node js + angular js application I defined a directive and a service in my controller like said here [Data not posting in multipart form data in angular and node js(File uploading with angular and node js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688806/data-not-posting-in-multipart-form-data-in-angular-and-node-jsfile-uploading-wi) 
It seems like it's not workig since my server is returning 500 internal error

my js file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: __dirname+'/../../uploads' });
router.post('/fileUpload',upload.single('myFile'),uploadFile);
function uploadFile(req,res,next) {

console.log(req.file); //returning undefined 
  }
```

In addition a directory 'uploads' is created but nothing is added to it and when I inspect the browser I find internal server error 500

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a post that solved my problem perfectly since I was dealing with multer, angular js and node js [nodejs + multer + angularjs for uploading without redirecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957006/nodejs-multer-angularjs-for-uploading-without-redirecting)
This is helpful!

Answer (score -2):

Try changing

```
router.post('/fileUpload',upload.single('myFile'),uploadFile);
```

to

```
router.post('/fileUpload',upload.single('file'),uploadFile);
```

Comment: how would changing the name of the file make a difference here?

Comment: Multer documentation suggest that the input type="file" name="value" in the upload tag and the upload.single('value') match !